# Hide second window behind the first

Tags: java

My first frame is big and second frame is smaller than first. My problem when I click the first window second window hide behind the first window. How can i solve it. Never hide second window behind  the first.

Comment: How are you supposed to do that when first frame is bigger than second. Please make your point very clear.

Comment: Do you want the second frame to be invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop the second JFrame from hiding behind the first one when clicking on the first one, you should apply the following method to the second JFrame:

```
secondFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

If you want to do this with JPanels in a JFrame you can use a [Layered Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)